# Opencv webcam with libusb driver python

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, libusb

I'm working with python and using wx for my GUI. I'm using OpenCv to capture frames from my webcam and this works fine when using the webcams default driver. However, I'm also trying to use pyUSB with a libusb backend to detect which USB devices are plugged in at any given moment. In order to use pyUSB to determine which devices are plugged in, I need to use libusb to generate a driver for the webcam. The driver generated from libusb is automatically installed and then I can use pyUSB's find usb.core.find method to enumerate the USB devices connected.

My problem is that now OpenCv is unable to capture frames. I believe my code actually gets a camera capture object and it gets the frames, but the frames are black. I can immediately check that the driver is causing the problem by uninstalling the libusb driver and reinstalling the default webcam driver. Do I need to instruct OpenCv to use this new libusb driver? If so, how? Google didn't turn up anything obvious.

Edit: In case it's important, I'm on Windows 7 64 bit using python 2.7.3

Comment: My solution was simply to move to linux. Luckily, I had that option. I can use pyusb to detect which USB devices are plugged in, without installing a third party driver (linux only). This isn't really a solution as much as a work around, but perhaps useful information for someone.